# onActivityResult not being triggered

Tags: java, android

I have three activities, A, B and C (code below). A calls B with startActivityforResult with an override for onActivityResult, B calls C with ActivityforResult too and onActivityResult to return the result to A. My problem is that onActivityResult is not being triggered. I think its due to I'm finishing the Activity from an function outside the onCreate, but I have no clue.

I've tried looking into another answers but didn't make it work.

I've tried with Intents but none of that seems to work.

MainActivity.java

```java
Button btn = findViewById(R.id.add);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addReminder();
            }
        });


      } //Finish of onCreate

    private void addReminder(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddRecActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_OK);

public void refresh() {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        refresh();
    }
    }
```

AddRecActivity.java

```java
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                cursor.moveToPosition(position);
                Medicina med = new Medicina(cursor);
                Intent intent = new Intent(AddRecActivity.this, RecFinishActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("NAME", med.getName());
                intent.putExtra("QUANTITY", med.getQuantity());
                intent.putExtra("TYPE", med.getType());
                intent.putExtra("PILLS", med.getPills());
                startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_OK);
            }
        });

    }//onCreate end here
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(RESULT_OK == resultCode){
            Log.i("Insercion:", "Insercion correcta");
        } else {
            Log.i("Insercion:", "Insercion fallida");
        }
        setResult(RESULT_OK);
        finish();
    }
```

RecFinishActivity.java

```java
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addRec(data.getString("NAME"), data.getInt("QUANTITY"), data.getString("TYPE"),
                        data.getInt("PILLS"));
            }
        });
    } //onCreate end here

    void addRec(String name, int quantity, String type, int pills){
        Consumo con = new Consumo(name, quantity, type, pills, true, Integer.parseInt(min.getText().toString()));
        long success = sRegistrosDbHelper.saveConsumo(con);
        setResult(RESULT_OK);
        finish();
    }
```

RecFinishActivity finish() is working, but AddRecActivity onResultActivity is not triggered, so this Activity doesn't finish and MainActivity doesn't get the result.

Expected behaviour: C finishes, B triggers onResultActivity and finish, A triggers onResultActivity and Refresh the Activity.

Comment: Do not call finish().

Comment: Then how I'm gonna end the activity?

Comment: public void refresh() {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

You called finish() before startActivity. Can you check that please.

Comment: That one is to refresh the Activity itself, that code is working fine @AnupamBose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StartActivityForResult takes in the intent and a requestCode as a parameter. You're passing the RESULT_OK instead. Try creating a unique code each time (it could be any integer), and on your onActivityResult look for that specific requestCode.

```
Intent i = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 100); //I'm using 100 as a requestCode
```

if on ActivityB you want to set the result as OK:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent(); //use this intent if you want to send dat back to the other activity
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
finish();
```

and on answer to that:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 100) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            //do something
        }
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            //do something if there's no result
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
here your problem is startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_OK); , the value of RESULT_OK is -1 which is ignored by internal call from startActivityforResult use any other request code like 
MainActivity :`
    Button btn = findViewById(R.id.add);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addReminder();
            }
        });


      } //Finish of onCreate

    private void addReminder(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddRecActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 100);

public void refresh() {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        refresh();
    }
    }


`AddRecActivity.java`
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                cursor.moveToPosition(position);
                Medicina med = new Medicina(cursor);
                Intent intent = new Intent(AddRecActivity.this, RecFinishActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("NAME", med.getName());
                intent.putExtra("QUANTITY", med.getQuantity());
                intent.putExtra("TYPE", med.getType());
                intent.putExtra("PILLS", med.getPills());
                startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
            }
        });

    }//onCreate end here
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(100 == requestCode){
            Log.i("Insercion:", "Insercion correcta");
        } else {
            Log.i("Insercion:", "Insercion fallida");
        }
        setResult(RESULT_OK);
        finish();
    }


`RecFinishActivity.java
`
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addRec(data.getString("NAME"), data.getInt("QUANTITY"), data.getString("TYPE"),
                        data.getInt("PILLS"));
            }
        });
    } //onCreate end here

    void addRec(String name, int quantity, String type, int pills){
        Consumo con = new Consumo(name, quantity, type, pills, true, Integer.parseInt(min.getText().toString()));
        long success = sRegistrosDbHelper.saveConsumo(con);
        setResult(RESULT_OK);
        finish();
    }`
you can use any value in request code other than 100,101, non negative value
```